# Split Dataframe with 1 column (multiple values) to multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 1 column having multiple values

````
                                            Mat Header
0      TURBINE , GAS ; MAKE: M/S HITACHI ; MODEL: H-25
1      TURBINE , GAS ; MAKE: M/S HITACHI ; MODEL: H-25

[43823 rows x 1 columns]```

How to split all values into different columns like :
``` Item     ???    Make         Model
    Turbine  Gas    M/S Hitachi  H-25
````

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60818915/pandas-split-columns-into-multiple-columns-by-two-delimiters has many of the ways to do this, with slightly different separators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split it like this (you need to change the column names):

```
df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']] = df['col'].str.split(';',expand=True)
```

Comment: Then extract characters after the colon for the last two columns. ... Or delete characters up to and including the colon in columns two and three

Comment: ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

Comment: @saimkhan - that statement works for the example you gave in your question.

Comment: I made a stupid mistake ! thanks a lot !!

Comment: it suddenly stopped working !!!